# How to break super class constructor chain?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

```
class Animal {
    protected Animal(){
        System.out.println("ANIMAL CONSTRUCTOR");
    }
    public void move(){
        System.out.println("ANIMAL Move");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    public Dog(){
        System.out.println("Dog Constructor");
    }
    public void move(){
        System.out.println("Dog move");
    }

}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Dog d = new Dog();
    d.move();
    }
}
```

The code above yields the result below:

```
ANIMAL CONSTRUCTOR 
Dog Constructor
Dog move
```

It seems that when dog instance is created, it also calls Animal constructor by default (implicitly).

Which is strange because I was thinking explicitly calling `super()` can do the same job.

Is there any way to break this constructor chain and let my dog instance only call Dog constructor?

if there is not, is there reason for it?

Comment: I think this might be an XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Why don't you want the `Animal` constructor to be invoked?

Comment: "Why" sets this question apart from the originally-identified question it was marked as a dupe of. That said, there almost certainly *is* an earlier version of this question that this could be closed and point to.

Comment: This question is largely (entirely?) answered by [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967662/any-way-to-not-call-superclass-constructor-in-java) combined with [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173019/why-is-constructor-of-super-class-invoked-when-we-declare-the-object-of-sub-clas).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It seems that when dog instance is created, it also calls Animal constructor by default (implicitly).

Yes.

> Which is strange because I was thinking explicitly calling super() can do the same job.

You can, yes, but if you don't, the compiler inserts a call to `super()` (with no args) at the beginning of your subclass constructor. The reason for allowing you to do it explicitly is that you may want to call a superclass constructor that accepts arguments.

> Is there any way to break this constructor chain and let my dog instance only call `Dog` constructor?

No.

> if there is not, is there reason for it?

Because `Dog` **is a(n)** `Animal`, and so the `Animal` class must have its chance to initialize the `Animal`-specific features of the object being created.

Consider:

```
class Animal {
    private Something useful;

    Animal() {
        this.useful = /*...something useful...*/;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    private String breed;

    Dog(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }
}
```

When you construct a `Dog` instance, in memory it looks like this:

```
+-------------+
|     Dog     |
+-------------+
| useful: ... |
| breed:  ... |
+-------------+
```

A `Dog` instance is a combination of what's defined by `Animal` and what's defined by `Dog`.

Now, suppose `Animal`'s constructor were never called: What value would `useful` have? Right! `null` (because I declared it as an object type). But `Animal`'s code quite clearly expects the constructor to set `useful` to something useful. If we could somehow bypass `Animal`'s constructor, we'd be breaking the class.

Comment: so `super()` is used to make it clear that it is inherited or to select from many other constructors?

Comment: @KeonKim: Yes. `super()` (literally, with no arguments) is purely a matter of style. I always do it, for instance, for exactly those reasons: To be clear about what's going on and specifically that I'm calling the no-arguments version. But some people quite reasonably argue that I shouldn't because the compiler always does it anyway and so they find it jarring to see it explicitly written. When you call `super(with, args, here)`, of course, that's required, because the compiler will never do that for you. (Not even when the superclass doesn't have a no-args constructor.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of stopping the `Animal` constructor from being called when you instantiate a child class. Essentially that's because the base class might contain fields that need to be set too.

(Note that the constructor to the implicit base class `java.lang.Object` is also called. You question is more about "missing out a constructor" somewhere in the inheritance heirarchy).

You could make `Animal` an `interface` if it doesn't contain any fields. Then it will not have a constructor. Using interfaces in this way allows you to define, for example, movement-like methods on objects that are not animals, such as vehicles. You are then stumbling upon a programming paradigm called *composition*.