# Asking some tips for using init in python

Tags: python

I tried to find out with googling, but it seems not explained.

There are four classes, for example, which are A, B, C, and D.

C is sub-class of D. A and B is calling C.

```py
    Class A:
        def __init__(self):
            self.c = C()

    Class B:
        def __init__(self):
           self.c = C()

    Class C(D):
        def __init__(self):
            print('it is C')

    Class D:
        def __init__(self):
            print('it is D')


    a = A()
    b = b()
```

In this case, it will initiate twice for Class C. So, 'it is C' and 'it is D' strings represent twice. And.. I think it's ... not normal.

Unlike Java, it seems that Python doesn't support constructor overloading.

In this case, can I call C only though? Or, could I get an advice for using init in Python?

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think that you cant pass in additional parameters to `__init__`? It works the same way as java

Comment: You create `C` twice in `A` and `B`, and `C` is extends `D`, so `D` constructor is also called. How is it different from Java? except of course you need to add `super().__init__()` to `C` `__init__`...

Comment: First, check indentation, is the indentation here correct?

Comment: By the way what is *constructor overriding*? there is no such thing in Java

Comment: Oh, I just want to use the constructor in different way, so.. if I call C(1) then, it says 'it is C', but if I call C() without any argument, then it says nothing.

Comment: Your current code cannot even run in python, can you show the actual code you're running?

Comment: I corrected your syntax and tried to run it which printed "it is C
it is C" are you not looking for this output

Comment: Sorry for my English... It is Overloading. I found its usage with if-else statement.

Comment: @ Paritosh : Oh.. That is pseudo code. It will give you an error because of indent.

Comment: The standard in Python is using [default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075044/initialize-parameter-of-method-with-default-value), there is no methods overloading, atleast not without third party modules.

Comment: `D` doesn't exist yet when you attempt to create `C`

Comment: @Guy, I read this article, but it is not what I want to get... https://stavshamir.github.io/python/2018/05/26/overloading-constructors-in-python.html

Comment: @owcred601 did u take a look at my answer. your question is not super clear on overloading part. but according to you comment where you say call C() and C(1), my answer could help

Comment: It's completely normal and it is working as intended. Java also calls the parent's constructor. You have to call the `super` constructor as it is pointed out here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967662/any-way-to-not-call-superclass-constructor-in-java

Comment: another way to do this is use default arguments,  most likely `argname=None`. then use if-else with the value of that argument

Comment: @Eshaka, Through your way, I can get the result I want. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You have several errors in your code: `class` not `Class`, checkout indentation, class definition order... see this:

```
class D:
    def __init__(self):
        print('it is D')

class C(D):
    def __init__(self):
        print('it is C')

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = C()

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = C()

a = A()
b = B()
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question itself, and just fixes typos and so on. While useful, this is not an answer here and should not have been posted as one.

Answer (score -2):

**method 1**

you can use the `*args` and `**kwargs`

[args and kwargs](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/args-and-kwargs)

you can get the `len(args)` and `len(kwargs.keys())`  (kwargs is a dict) and program different parts depending on the number of arguments. this can work like a constructor overloading

example:

```
__init__(self, *args):
   if len(args)==0:
      # constructor one 
   if len(args)==1:
      # constructor two
```

**method 2**

use default arguments, most likely `argname=None`. then use if-else with the value of that argument

simple example :

```
__init__(self, arg1=None):
       if arg1==None:
          # constructor one 
       else:
          # constructor two
```